# Can I fit a regression line to group medians?

Tags: regression, modeling, median

I have a large dataset that makes generating scatterplots time inefficient. Wondering if I can fit a regression line to group medians?

Firstly, all groups have a similar distribution of both variables, so the median is representative of the group.

Is this a faux pas?

[image]

Comment: You can do this.  But you can do it better by evaluating the uncertainties in those medians.  To do that well, it would help to know a little bit more about the data, such as how many values each median represents and what you know or assume about their underlying distributions.

Comment: Hey @whuber good to see you again! I would hazard that each of these medians represents around 1.4 million data points on average...which im guessing is problematic. Values from the y axis are all power-law distributed (Pareto-I, actually) and the x axis values are Gamma distributed (I have assessed this separately)

Comment: This is the opposite of problematic: you have incredibly detailed information about the distributions.  Consider using richer, more powerful visualizations and models.  At a minimum you could replace each point with a sketch of the joint distribution of (distance, canopy volume) within each group.  A "sketch" could be contours of a 2D kernel density estimate, for instance.  This would be especially helpful for judging how to perform a regression, because it would reveal the uncertainty in the regressor values, which could be important depending on what you're trying to show.

Comment: whuber this is fantastic advice, really appreciate you helping me out. do you think seaborn has this capability (in python)?

Comment: I don't know, but `R` has packages 2D KDE estimation.  Consider subsampling your dataset--a simple random sample of a few tens of thousands of observations would likely work just fine (or a stratified sample in case the dataset is hugely imbalanced).  That will help you make short work of the computation and visualization.  Once you have figured out what you need to do and how you need to do it you can worry about applying your methods to the entire dataset (if that even turns out to be necessary).

Comment: @whuber is it normal for the standard deviation to be quite large in these massive datasets?

Comment: "Quite large" has no inherent meaning.  The SD of the median should be within some expected range because it's not appreciably affected by extreme or outlying data.